# Primefaces' p:dialog with form doesn't behave as expected

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I generated a Primefaces based CRUD website starting from JPA Entities with netbeans and after adjusting the Update dialog to fit my needs I am experiencing several problems. The domain Model is quite easy: I have an entity Invitation which contains several Guests.

```
@Entity
public class Invitation implements Serializable {
...
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "invitationId")
    private List<Guest> guestList;
    public List<Guest> getGuestList() {
        return guestList;
    }
...
}
```

I have an overview page (list.xhtml) where all the invitations are listed and the user can pick one to edit it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" template="/template/layout.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form id="InvitationListForm">
            <p:dataTable var="invitation" id="datalist"
                value="#{invitationController.invitations}" resizableColumns="true"
                selectionMode="single" selection="#{invitationController.selected}"
                rowKey="#{invitation.invitationId}" paginator="true" rows="10"
                rowsPerPageTemplate="10,30,50,100" draggableColumns="true">
                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update="createButton editButton " />
                <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" update="createButton editButton " />

                <p:column headerText="Name">
                    <h:outputText id="invitationName" value="#{invitation.name}" />
                </p:column>
                ...

                <f:facet name="footer">
                        <p:commandButton id="createButton" icon="ui-icon-plus"
                            value="#{msgs.lbl_add_new}" update=":InvitationCreateForm"
                            oncomplete="PF('InvitationCreateDialog').show()" />

                        <p:commandButton id="editButton" icon="ui-icon-pencil"
                            value="#{msgs.lbl_edit}" update=":InvitationEditForm"
                            oncomplete="PF('InvitationEditDialog').show()"
                            disabled="#{empty invitationController.selected}" />
                </f:facet>
            </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>
        <ui:include src="create.xhtml" />
        <ui:include src="edit.xhtml" />
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Note that layout.xhtml doesn't contain any form (no nested forms).
The dialog edit.xhtml is divided into 2 parts: one where the user can enter the invitation "head" information and another one with a datatable where she can edit / add / delete guests.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head></h:head>
<body>
    <ui:composition>
        <h:form id="InvitationEditForm">
            <p:dialog id="InvitationEditDlg" widgetVar="InvitationEditDialog"
                modal="true" resizable="false" appendTo="@(body)"
                header="#{msgs.lbl_add_new}">

                <h:panelGroup id="display">
                    <p:panelGrid columns="2"
                        rendered="#{invitationController.selected != null}">
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{msgs.lbl_name}" for="name" />
                        <p:inputText id="name"
                            value="#{invitationController.selected.name}" required="true"/>
                ...
                </p:panelGrid>
                <p:dataTable var="aGuest" id="guestTable" style="width: 1200px;"
                        value="#{invitationController.selected.guestList}"
                        resizableColumns="false" rowIndexVar="idx" draggableColumns="true">
                        <p:column width="80" headerText="#{msgs.lbl_name}">
                            <p:inputText id="guestName" value="#{aGuest.name}" />
                        </p:column>
                        ...
                        <p:column width="20">
                            <p:commandButton
                                actionListener="#{invitationController.addNewGuest}"
                                id="addGuestButton" update="guestTable" icon="ui-icon-plusthick"
                                title="+" />
                            <p:commandButton
                                actionListener="#{invitationController.deleteGuest(idx)}"
                                id="deleteGuestButton" update="guestTable"
                                icon="ui-icon-minusthick" title="-" immediate="true"
                                rendered="#{invitationController.selected.guestList.size()>1}" />
                        </p:column>
                        </p:dataTable>

                    <p:commandButton actionListener="#{invitationController.save}"
                        value="#{msgs.lbl_save}"
                        update="display,:InvitationListForm:datalist,:growl"
                        oncomplete="handleSubmit(args,'InvitationEditDialog');" />
                    <p:commandButton value="#{msgs.lbl_cancel}" immediate="true"
                        actionListener="#{invitationController.cancel}"
                        onclick="PF('InvitationEditDialog').hide()" />
                </h:panelGroup>

            </p:dialog>
        </h:form>
    </ui:composition>
</body>
</html>
```

And the Controller

```
@SessionScoped
@Named
public class InvitationController implements Serializable {
    private Invitation selected; //with getter and setter

}
```

Now, I think my problem should be in the combination of p:dialog and h:form.

The original generated version of edit.xhtml had the form InvitationEditForm nested within the dialog and not the contrary as I posted above. The problem with that was after clicking editButton the dialog was loaded, but the dataTable was always filled with guests of the first Invitation I selected in my session (more strangely, suppose the first invitation in the session had just a guest A: after selecting an Invitation with 2 guests B and C I got A and B displayed). As the controller was returning the right guestList(), I supposed there was a problem with update and inverting form and display solved this problem..

Unfortunately this didn't solve all the problems, as now the actionListener for addGuestButton and deleteGuestButton doesn't get invoked anymore..

I am really confused: can you please help me to fix my code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is quite convoluted. Can you boil the problem statement down to something more readable?

Comment: I suggest that you put a few `System.out.println` along your code execution, right from when the list has just been retrieved from the database to the time just before being displayed on the page. You need to know if the initial data is correct or not and exactly where it has gone wrong along the way.

Comment: In general its a very good idea to override hashCode() and equals() on the entities when reversing in Netbeans (well, always), as at least dropdowns and datatables can mess up otherwise. To me it sounds a bit like you miss them here.